# ' l am late' vs. '…I m being late' vs '…I m going to be late'

Tags: meaning

lets assume these two different situations:

1. I must be at work at 7 but now it is 7:05 and I am still at home
2. I must be at work at 7 its 6:50 but i know I'm not arriving to my work on time

what would we say in these situations , "you are late", "being late", or"going to be late" and why i don't know can anybody explain thanks.

Comment: I am confused regarding the pronouns. Is it "I" or "you" that is late?

Comment: @Cardinal, lets assume someone else are talking to me im late and for instance my brother wants to remind me that what would he say in these situations

Comment: Thank you for your note, I suggest that you join us on ELL's main chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow

I often check the chat room, and I would be happy if I could help you. I am an intermediate-level learner though! There are a lot of awesome people there who, I am sure, would be able to help you better than me! :-)

Comment: [to arrive **at work** on time].

Answer (score 1):

(1) You are late. You *should have been* at work by 7.00.

(2) You are going to be late. (It's not 7.00 yet, but you have no chance of getting to work on time.)

Comment: 2) is interesting — if I were talking to someone else I would probably say "You are going to be late", but if talking about myself, I would probably say "I am late" in that case (as in, I'm not 'on schedule' — I had planned to leave the house before now in order to arrive in time)